# Error al actualizar (sdk manager)

Tags: android-studio

muy buenas amigos y amigas de la comunidad, he aquí molestando de nuevo, les cuento que acabo de realizar una actualización del sdk manager del 33 al 34, he aquí el build gradle que estoy utilizando para mi aplicación android, soy nuevo en estas lides, esta aplicación es para trabajarla bajo una base de datos creada en mysql, lo prometido:

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 34

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.gestion"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 34
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
}

dependencies {
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1'
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', includes: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
implementation 'androidx.activity:activity:1.8.0'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.6.2'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0-alpha03'
implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.6.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint -layout-solver:2.0.4'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout-solver:2.0.4'
implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}
```

por lo cual me ha derivado en el siguiente error:

```
Cannot resolve method 'show' in 'AlertDialog'
```

en lo cual el error se refleja en el siguiente código:

```
txtfecharecepcion.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Calendar calendario = Calendar.getInstance();
            int day = calendario.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            int month = calendario.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int year = calendario.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(
                    ingreso2.super.getActivity(), new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    String formattedDay = String.format("%02d", dayOfMonth);
                    String formattedMonth = String.format("%02d", monthOfYear + 1);
                    String selectedDate = formattedDay + "/" + formattedMonth + "/" + year;
                    txtfecharecepcion.setText(selectedDate);
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
                    if (txtpatente1 != null){
                        builder.setMessage(R.string.dialog_message).setTitle(R.string.dialog_title);
                        builder.setMessage("¿Desea ingresar los datos del trabajador?").setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("Si", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                llenarSpinner4();
                                spdesabollador.requestFocus();
                            }
                        }).setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                txtfechaentrega.requestFocus();
                            }
                        });
                        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                        alert.setTitle("Gestión");
                        **alert.show();**
                    } else {
                        txtpatente1.requestFocus();
                    }
                }
            }, year, month, day);
            datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
            datePickerDialog.show();
        }
    });
```

el cual para mayor claridad se da en la línea del alert.show();, he tratado de solucionarlo pero no he podido llevo dos días metido en esto y nada de nada, por eso les molesto, no se si el error esta en las dependencias o si en algún import los cuales ya los revise uno por uno y no creo que sea el problema ya que a medida que voy codificado se agregan los import que se utilizan, pero si gustan las puedo agregar no hay problema, por otro lado les adjunto unas imágenes del sdk manager del sdk 34 el cual si falta algo por instalar:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

a continuación lo demas:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que quiero es que me guíen, si falta algo por instalar o falta alguna dependencia, soy novato en estas lides y me gusta aprender, a medida que voy avanzando. Además no me gusta molestar mucho a la comunidad, pero cuando uno no puedo debe recurrir a la ayuda de ustedes, de la cual siempre he recibido apoyo, favor de ayudarme y desde ya muchas gracias. Por otro lado si necesitan algo mas no duden en solicitarlo.